# Python3: Why does __spec__ work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where does the variable `__spec__` come from?

```
$ brew install python3
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan  5 2015, 11:57:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

# Under Python 2.7.x this gives a NameError
>>> None is __spec__
True
```

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue19697 has more implementation info in case anyone is interested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Python Language Reference, Part 5: The Import System](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__spec__) (emphasis mine):

> The `__spec__` attribute must be set to the module spec that was used when importing the module. This is used primarily for introspection and during reloading. Setting `__spec__` appropriately applies equally to [modules initialized during interpreter startup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/toplevel_components.html#programs). **The one exception is `__main__`, where `__spec__` is set to None in some cases**.
>
> *New in version 3.4.*

Comment: '[...] \_\_spec\_\_ attribute must be set to the module spec [...]': to me this is a circular definition and not explanatory. I am missing the meaning of `spec`. After searching a bit more I am still not elucidated what the `spec` is. I know this is an old post, but maybe the best at it. Would it be possible for you to edit the answer with a couple more details?

Comment: @deponovo It sounds like you're looking for the [importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec)

Answer (score 6):

According to Python 3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#main-spec), `__spec__` is always `None` if you are using interactive promt:

> When Python is started with the -m option, `__spec__` is set to the
>   module spec of the corresponding module or package. `__spec__` is also
>   populated when the `__main__` module is loaded as part of executing a
>   directory, zipfile or other sys.path entry.
>
> In the remaining cases `__main__.__spec__` **is set to None**, as the code
>   used to populate the `__main__` does not correspond directly with an
>   importable module:
>
> - **interactive prompt**
> - -c switch
> - running from stdin
> - running directly from a source or bytecode file